# How can I get enough Stingers for a Blade of Grass?

Tags: terraria

I'm look for a blade of grass to make the night's edge. I got all the jungle spores and eleven stinger, but the hornets, and big stingers stopped spawning. How can I get more stingers?

Comment: Are you asking about Terraria?  Or Minecraft?

Comment: @Frank from the items mentioned it's absolutely Terraria, edited

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're playing the PC version, as of 1.2, Hornets and Spiked Slimes will both drop stingers. I don't believe either one of them should have the potential to "stop spawning," unless something has impacted your Underground Jungle biome in such a way as to prevent normal creature spawning.

If you have any Corruption or Crimson that's interfering with your jungle, you should look into either counteracting it ASAP, or creating a new (properly protected) jungle elsewhere. You could also generate a new world and harvest its jungle, if you wanted to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

Huh. Sounds rather peculiar. Now I will mention things only to exist before 9.1.1 because I play on iOS, but I have an idea. Try to find a hornet statue and go to the jungle. Find some wire, from a random trap or manually made. Place layer of lava; thin and thick enough to destroy the mobs just in a small confined place you mine out, and put down the hornet statue. At the other side of the wire place a pressure plate and repeatedly jump for hornets that instantly die. Note if they don't spawn, your jungle may not be counted as one; try placing down mud and letting grass spread onto it.
I would explain further but this is already rhydonculously long.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the wall of flesh to turn your world into hardmode and then you can also kill moss hornets for extra stigers in your trip through the underground jungle the next time you venture there.so now instead of just killing hornets and spiked slimes you can also kill moss hornets